# Trouble with intent in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I started in the android programming and and I encountered a problem when i tried to send data from my Adapter to an another activity
.
I want to show the content of "`description`" in my other activity when I click on an item.

**MyAdapter class :**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private final List<FakeNews> list = FakeNewsList.all;

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_cell, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        FakeNews pair = list.get(position);
        holder.display(pair);
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView name;
        private final TextView description;

        private FakeNews currentPair;

        public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name = ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name));
            description = ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description));

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent =  new Intent(MyViewHolder.this ,Affich.class);
                    intent.putExtra("description", String.valueOf((description)));
                    startActivity(intent);



                }
            });
        }

        public void display(FakeNews pair) {
            currentPair = pair;
            name.setText(pair.title);

        }
    }

}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you do not really want to pass the `TextView` to your next activity, but the content which is shown in it. Also, you need to pass a `Context` to the Intent and `startActivity()` is a method of an activity, so you need to call it on the context:

```
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent =  new Intent(view.getContext() ,Affich.class);
            intent.putExtra("description", description.getText().toString());
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `Context` or `Activity` instance into your adapter class.

then while starting new `Activity` and suppose instance variable is `mContext` use like this-

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(mContext ,Affich.class);
intent.putExtra("description", String.valueOf((description)));
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass value from `TextView` to your new activity, do this:

`intent.putExtra("description", description.getText().toString());`

on your new activity, get the description value using:

`String descriptionValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");`